# RichTextBox in WPF - Getting last block of text

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textblock

Could anybody share the idea how to get the last block of a `RichTextBox`'s document in WPF?
I tried with code:

```
Block pg = box.Document.ContentEnd.Paragraph.PreviousBlock;
box.Document.Blocks.Remove(pg);
```

But it doesn't work (the first line is throwing exceptions).

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

` Cannot obtain value of local or argument '<this>' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away. System.Delegate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this must help you:

```
box.Document.Blocks.Remove(box.Document.Blocks.LastBlock)
```